# Callback for Menu to list Submenu items in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I created the Menu for my Matlab GUI which is "File" under which sub menus are Open, Save & Exit.
When i clicked on the File Menu, it will list down the sub menu items Open, Save & Exit.

I want to assign a shortcut key for this file menu instead of clicking the file menu when i press the "Alt+F" it has the show the list down of sub menu items. I dont want to use the shortcut option provided by the Guide, i want to hard code that shortcut Key.

I have coded for the combination of the key detection (Alt+F) but which function/call back has to be used for the listing down of the sub menu items ?

Answer (score -1):

https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~nnikvand/Coderep/gui%20examples/GUI.pdf
page 37

MATLAB menus support accelerator keys and keyboard mnemonics. Accelerator keys are `"CTRL+key"` combinations that cause a menu item to be executed without opening the menu first.

For example, the accelerator `key "0"` might be assigned to the File/Open
menu item. In that case, the keyboard combination `CTRL+o` will cause the `File/Open` callback function to be executed.

A few `CRTL+key` combinations are reserved for the use of the host operating system.

These combinations differ between PC and UNIX systems; consult the MATLAB online documentation to determine which combinations are legal for your type of computer. Accelerator keys are defined by setting the Accelerator property in a `uimenu` object.

Keyboard mnemonics are single letters that can be pressed to cause a menu item to execute once the menu is open. The keyboard mnemonic letter for a given menu item is underlined. For top-level menus, the keyboard mnemonic is executed by pressing `ALT` plus the mnemonic key at the same time. Once the top-level menu is open, simply pressing the mnemonic key will cause a menu item to execute. Figure 1.29 illustrates the use of keyboard mnemonics. The File menu is opened with the keys `ALT+f`, and once it is opened, the Exit menu item can be executed by simply typing `"x"`.

Keyboard mnemonics are defined by placing the ampersand character `(&)` before the desired mnemonic letter in the Label property. The ampersand will not be displayed, but the following letter will be underlined, and it will act as a mnemonic key. For example, the Label property of the Exit menu item in Figure 1.29 is `'E&xit'`.

Comment: You need to use paragraphs, as a single large block of text is difficult to read. To create paragraphs, use two return carriages, or for a single new line add two spaces at the end of the previous line